# How to stop Laravel from caching ENV file, is there a way?

Tags: laravel

I discovered that I can't change something in the .env file and have Laravel pick it in next run. For example I changed

```
APP_ENV=production
```

to

```
APP_ENV=local
```

And upon running

```
artisan migrate
```

I still get asked if I am sure I want to run migration in production environment. Is there a way to get around this and not have to clear cache every time .env file is updated?

Comment: Look in your `config/app.php`. There should be something like `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production')`. It that correct?

Comment: For security reasons is the `.env` file not accessible in a production environment. It is indeed cached instead (/bootstrap/cache/config.php) through composer update/install or php artisan config:cache commands. So yes. In production you don't have a choice to reset the config file(s). Also the long process `queue:work` needs to be restarted. The behavior of the View caches are different as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to run `config:clear` and `cache:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one command to clear all caches in Laravel:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

It would clear all the caches:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `route:clear`, `config:clear`, and `view:clear`. After `composer dump-autoload`.